# Finding Directory traversal vulnerability

Tags: penetration-test, directory-traversal

I want to test a web application for [Directory Traversal](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal) (DT) vulnerability.

I have gone through a lot of google pages but can't find a clear description. I've tried using `../.././../../etc/passwd` along with the URLS however not sure where I'm heading.

Please help me find any links where I can read and go ahead testing the DT vulnerability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Directory Traversal is an HTTP exploit which allows attackers to access restricted directories and execute commands outside of the web server's root directory.

I'll help you with an example on this.

2. In web applications with dynamic pages, input is usually received from browsers through GET or POST request methods. Here is an example of a GET HTTP request URL:

https://test.example.com/show.asp?view=oldpage.html

3. With this URL, the browser requests the dynamic page show.asp from the server and with it also sends the parameter "view" with the value of "oldpage.html". When this request is executed on the web server, show.asp retrieves the file oldpage.html from the server's file system, renders it and then sends it back to the browser which displays it to the user. The attacker would assume that show.asp can retrieve files from the file system and sends this custom URL:

https://test.webarticles.com/show.asp?view=../../../../../Windows/system.ini ==> This will cause the dynamic page to retrieve the file system.ini from the file system and display it to the user.

4. The expression ../ instructs the system to go one directory up which is commonly used as an operating system directive.

Answer (score 1):

A directory traversal vulnerability is a vulnerability easy found through automation, so it's better to just run whichever tool you want to find if a site is vulnerable.

However, if still you want to manual check whether or not a site is vulnerable, you need to identify a point where a file is loaded, i.e. `test.php?file=myfile.txt` and then guess the physical path on the server.

Assuming a standard installation, let's say `/var/www/html/yoursite/test.php`, you would need four back jumps (`../../../../`) to get to the root and then go for `etc/passwd`.